# Can I use any basis for the spectral theorem or does it have to be the eigenbasis?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a Hermitian operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $H$ with eigenvalues $\{a_i\}$ and eigenvectors $v_i$ forming a complete basis, one can write $A$ as:
$$ A = \sum_i a_i v_i v_i^\dagger,  $$
where $v^\dagger$ is the Hermitian conjugate of $v$.

Suppose there is another complete basis $\{w_i\}$. Can I also use the spectral decomposition with this $w$-basis, instead of the eigenbasis $\{v_i\}$?
$$ A = \sum_i a_i w_i w_i^\dagger  $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. The point of an eigenbasis is that it diagonalises the operator; it works on each basis vector separately and independently of the others. That diagonalisation is exactly what you see in the sum.

Take, for instance, the two-dimensional case with $A$ represented by $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ in some basis $u_i$. Then that basis is an eigenbais, and you get
$$
A = 1\cdot u_1u_1^\dagger + 2\cdot u_2u_2^\dagger
$$
If you take a new basis, say $v_1 = u_1+u_2$ and $v_2 = u_1-u_2$, then in that basis we have that $A$ is represented by $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1.5&-0.5\\-0.5&1.5\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Of course, the matrix is still symmetric / Hermitian, because change of basis cannot change that fact. But if you want to decompose it in something like the above sum it's not enough with $v_1v_1^\dagger$ and $v_2v_2^\dagger$. You need $v_1v_2^\dagger$ and $v_2v_1^\dagger$ terms as well, as there are now non-zero off-diagonal elements:
$$
A = 1.5\cdot v_1v_1^\dagger + 1.5\cdot v_2v_2^\dagger - 0.5\cdot v_1v_2^\dagger - 0.5\cdot v_2v_1^\dagger
$$

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for answering. My question arises from the solutions of an exam, where the author apparently used the spectral theorem (exam: https://phys.uic.edu/docs/default-source/qualifying-exam-problems-and-solutions/2013/qm_2013.pdf, solutions: https://phys.uic.edu/docs/default-source/qualifying-exam-problems-and-solutions/2013/qm_2013_soln.pdf). In question 1a), the spectral theorem with a non-eigenbasis is used to show that the operator B has only positive eigenvalues. If I follow your reasoning, this solution does not make sense, does it?

Comment: @Stephan No, that's something else. Here it's not the case that they have a $B$ and they decompose it using the eigenbasis of $A$. Rather it's that they use the eigenbasis and spectral decomposition of $A$ to _construct_ $B$ in the first place.

Comment: I see, but how can they argue that $|\lambda_i|$ are the eigenvalues of $B$ if this is not a spectral decomposition of $B$?

Comment: @Stephan It _is_ a spectral decomposition of $B$. That's exactly what $B$ is. It's defined as the matrix with that exact spectral decomposition.

Comment: Ah, I think now I get it: we define $B$ in such a way that it shares its eigenbasis with $A$. So as a corollary, $[A,B]=0$, right?

Comment: @Stephan Yes, that's it.